# Finding Facebook ID from URL

Tags: url, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

In Facebook's documentation it says you can find the ID from a URL, and that used to be the case. It doesn't appear to be true anymore.

This example is straight from Facebook's API Documentation:

--------------FACEBOOK DOCS---------------------

### The "ids" query parameter also accepts URLs. This is useful for finding IDs of URLs in the Open Graph. For example: https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/

But when you click on that link it gives you:

```
{
   "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/": {
      "id": "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/",
      "shares": 18226,
      "comments": 7
   }
}
```

Which does NOT include the real Facebook ID for this example URL. If I go to the debugger and enter this URL I can find the ID, which is: 380728101301

So how can I find the ID without using the Open Graph Debugger? I need to be able to get IDs through the code on my site, and can't manually visit the debugger every time.. anyone know how to do this now?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

There is one possibility with FQL:

```
SELECT url,site,id FROM object_url WHERE url = 'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500';
```

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

Comment: Hi Luschn - thanks, but that still returns incorrect information.. the "ID" it gives back is 7523336301, which is not the ID for the URL. If I go to http://graph.facebook.com/7523336301 I get an OAuthException saying it needs an access token, plus I already know that the correct ID is the one from the debugger (380728101301). If I do http://graph.facebook.com/380728101301 I get the valid details for the URL..

Comment: sorry, i did not try the id before. the problem is, it´s very important how you use the url. i removed the trailing slash and get a different id with the FQL (edited in the answer). looks like a better one: http://graph.facebook.com/118133258218514

Comment: you know what, i have an idea...what if you get an older version of the og tags with a different call? i mean, afaik it gets stored exactly as it gets it. so, in one version there is a trailing slash, in one there isn´t...now it would just be interesting to get the newest version...

Comment: Thanks for helping on this! Unfortunately it looks like this one, even though it actually DOES return results about the page, doesn't actually include the real details. For example, it says the page has 12 Likes, when really there are more like 20,000. The ID returned from the debugger provides the same information about the URL except with no Like information. I can't figure out how to access the most accurate and complete info!